# Отображение карты google на своем сайте

Tags: google-maps

На одной странице есть две карты: Yandex-map, Google-map. Причем активна бывает только одна.

Предназначение у карт: показывать выбранный объект.

Изначально активна Yandex-карта. Отображение и все работает нормально. При выборе объекта, он оказывается по середине места отображения карты.
[image]

При переключении карты на Google-map, возникает вот такая ошибка:
[image]

То есть, по какой-то причине mapcenter сместился в левый верхний угол. Проверила бы изначальный mapcenter, но заметила интересный факт: если изменить масштаб отображения в браузере (путем ctrl+ролик мышки), то карта начинает отображаться правильно. Дальнейшие переключения карт происходят нормально.

Ну и что это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось проще пареной репы: просто у меня первоначально для блока, где находится google-map стояло: `display:none`. Если это убрать, то отображение карты становится правильным.

Comment: Значит, вопрос можно того... удалить?